# gene manipulation books for beginners

Tags: book-recommendation

Are there any introductory book to explain gene manipulation in yeast for non-biologist?

I had a look at [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119072565) and now I have some ideas. I like to read another book at the same level which is more applied/practical. I find [this book chapter](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4939-1363-3_5) useful too, but I find it a bit more difficult to follow. Also video lectures are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by gene manipulation? Do you want protocols for yeast transformation?

Comment: For example, as I understood there is a plasmid which is a circular DNA. We introduce this plasmid to yeast so that the plasmid with its marker replace the desired gene. To achieve this we need to look at the flanking side of the gene to be deleted. So the plasmid must have these flanking parts. But how do I design the plasmid in for example snapgene software and how do I construct the plasmid say with PCR or other methods? After I make the plasmid then I can follow some protocol to do the transformation.

Comment: I think the information you are looking for would be contained in a genetic engineering book. not only for yeast but all eukaryotic and prokaryotes cells. I'm afraid that there will not be a book on that topic for a non-biologist but the topic is usually covered during Bachelor/Master studies.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the information you are looking for could be covered on this website:https://www.addgene.org/protocols/

Not only has addgene a protocol section, it also has an education section for understanding the concepts of genetic/molecular cloning: https://www.addgene.org/mol-bio-reference/

The material is for biologist, but should be relatively easy to understand for you are starting.

They also have a nice ebook which should cover some of the topics you asked: https://info.addgene.org/download-addgenes-ebook-plasmids-101-3rd-edition

Hope that helps!